# Anderson localization in 1d, 2d and 3d

Tags: condensed-matter

Why in 1d and 2d systems, all states will be localized for infinitesimal disorder, but in 3d only states with energy lower below mobility edge will be localized?

Answer (score 2):

- 1D : all states are localized
- 2D : all states are localized ; the length scale of localization
  grows exponentially with E and  marginal dimension for the Anderson
  transition
- 3D : mobility edge ; finite localization for $l_B <~  \lambda/(2\pi)$

**Some good references**

- LSP et al., Phys. Rev. Lett. 98, 210401 (2007)
- J. Billy et al.,   Nature 453, 891 (2008)
- M. Piraud et al., Phys. Rev. A 83, 031603(R)    (2011)